# Load List of images consequtively. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, pageviews

I am building a comics app. In order to make comic chapters load faster. I want images to load one by one consequtively. When an image finishes loading, it is presented directly into a pageview. I do not know how to load images one by one and edit the page view to present them.

Comment: using streambuilder https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. Like a simple example on how to establish that for images.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make load image faster you can try use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package like this:

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

It will show placeholder until the image loaded, so the user can see how many image there is and wait until it loaded, and errorWidget to show if some image were getting trouble. So I suggest to use it, it's easier. Unless you want some complicated code you can try use `ScrollController` put it inside your `ListView.builder`. Initialize your scroll controller in initState like this :

```
     final _scrollController = ScrollController();
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _scrollController.addListener(() {
          if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
              _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
// scroll has reach end, now load more images.
            loadMore();
          }
        });
      }
```

You can't use `setState` inside `initState` so that's why I create another method to call it like this:

```
  Future<void> loadMore() async {
    final response = await api.get("curated?per_page=50&page=$_currentPage");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var tempList = Pages.fromJson(response.data);
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
        wallpaper.addAll(tempList.photos);
      });
    }

    return null;
  }
```

So there you go I hope you can understand, and yes it is more complicated, so like I said I suggest you use `CachedNetworkImage`.

Comment: Thanks for example but I cannot use cached network image because my images have a dynamic url.

Comment: Alright, you can use scroll controller then, or make a button to load next image or smth

Answer (score 0):

use a StreamBuilder it will do all the work for u.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. Like a simple example on how to establish that for images. sorry for the late reply

Comment: getImageFunction(){
.............
..........
}

StreamBuilder(
stream : getImageFunction,
builder: .................
)

Each time the getImageFunction receives a image from the internet or whereever you are fetching from the stream builder will build a new Widget accordingly. If that is what you want,